# module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' not found

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make an **authentication to my flask application**, and then I started to follow this tutorial :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login

Then I got the following problem :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2020 21:46:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/4Linux/flask_auth_app/project/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 338, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 326, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 314, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 247, in locate_app
    "\n\n{tb}".format(name=module_name, tb=traceback.format_exc())
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "project", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/gabriel_rc/4Linux/flask_auth_app/project/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

Ps : The following archive */home/gabriel_rc/4Linux/flask_auth_app/project/****init**.py*** it's identical as the tutorial that I mentioned.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering me. Well, i received this : Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy in ./auth/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.4.4)

Comment: This means your Flask application does not run in the same environment as the one you installed flask-sqlalchemy into. If you use a virtualenv, make sure both Flask and its plugins use it.